# JavaFX: Get image from FileChooser and save it in a byte[]

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I want to select an image using `FileChooser` and then save the selected image in a byte[] variable, I open the dialog

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
```

Now, How can I get the image file from `FileChooser` and save it in byte[] variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Files.readAllBytes(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)):

```java
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG", "*.png"));
File pngImage = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(window);
if (pngImage != null) {
    try {
        byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(pngImage.toPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File couldn't be read to byte[].");
    }
}
```

An alternative: [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html):

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(pngImage));
```